# cleaning up and repairing server after multiple hard shutdowns

Tags: server, ssh, fsck, port-forwarding, busybox

I've been having some issues lately with my ubuntu server.  First it started having issues port forwarding my jupyter notebook server.  Then I was having issues ssh in to the server.  When I connected directly it was unresponsive, just kept scrolling the same set of logging messages over and over again.  So I did a hard shut down, which got me a "busybox v1.27.2 (Ubuntu 1:1.27.2-2ubuntu3.4) built-in shell (ash)" and initramfs prompt.  I tried typing "exit" which got me stuck in trace.  So another hard shutdown followed by booting to advanced and dropping in to root terminal.  At that point I ran "fsck -y /" and it seemed to fix things for about a day, then started having the same port forwarding and ssh issues, followed by a hard shutdown and busybox error.  This time when I tried dropping in to root and running "fsck -y /" got messages about not being able to do it because it was mounted and aborted.  So I booted from live media and ran "fsck -y" on the partitions where I have my operating system and boot efi.  The output from the commands is below.  I rebooted, everything seems fine.  I'm just wondering if anyone has any clue what the issue might be and any additional steps (like running sudo apt-get upgrade)?

code and output:

```
sudo fsck -y /dev/nvme1n1p2
```

fsck from util-linux 2.31.1
e2fsck 1.44.1 (24-Mar-2018)
/dev/nvme1n1p2: clean, 1449530/15237120 files, 50756607/60918016 blocks

```
sudo fsck -y /dev/nve1n1p2
```

fsck from util-linux 2.31.1
e2fsck 1.44.1 (24-Mar-2018)
/dev/nvme1n1p2: clean, 1449530/15237120 files, 50756607/60918016 blocks

```
sudo fsck -y /dev/nvme1n1p1
```

fsck from util-linux 2.31.1
fsck.fat 4.1 (2017-01-24)
0x41: Dirty bit is set.  Fs was not properly unmounted and some dataa may be corrupt.
Automatically removing dirty bit.
Performing chages.
/dev/nvme1n1p1: 10 files, 1691/130812 clusters

ran "sudo fsck -y /dev/nvme1n1p1" again and got

fsck from util-linux 2.31.1
fsck.fat 4.1 (2017-01-24)
/dev/nvme1n1p1: 10 files, 1691/130812 clusters

Comment: `fsck` on a disk with any mounted partitions is a path to corruption. Both the kernel snd `fsck` think they have the ONLY copy of the disk's metadata. Boot from a live distribution or your install medium in "Try Ubuntu" mode. Don't use `-y` on `fsck` unless you're willing to blindly accept `fsck`'s decisions.

Comment: @waltinator that's what he did according to the question. Furthermore, it's the *partition* that has to be unmounted; fsck doesn't care about disks, it cares about file systems (or partitions).